# ¿Cómo obtener la fila o columna de una matriz que tenga solo elementos pares en Matlab?

Tags: matrices, matlab

Puedo crear la matriz de MxN necesaria, pero necesito saber cuales de sus columnas o filas contienen números pares:

```
clc

m=input('Ingrese Nro de filas:  ')
n=input('Ingrese Nro de columnas:  ')

a=[]
M=[]

for i=1:m
    
    for j=1:n
        printf('a[%d, %d]', i,j)
        a(i,j) = input('') 
        M(i,j)= mod(a(i,j),2)

       
    end
    
end
disp(a)
disp(M)
```

He tratado de buscar una solución a partir del cálculo individual del residuo de cada elemento para ver si es par o impar, pero necesito evaluar cada fila y columna, ¿alguna idea?

[image: Resultado de la ejecución]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Por ahora te recomiendo que dividas tu problema en tres: ¿cómo saber si un número es par? ¿Cómo comprobar si lo con todos los elementos de una fila? ¿Cómo comprobar si lo son todos los elementos de una columna?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de forma matricial:

```
A=randi(100,10) % construye la matriz

impares=mod(A,2)
pares=~mod(A,2)

cantidad_de_pares_por_fila = sum(~mod(A,2),1) % sum(pares,1)
cantidad_de_pares_por_columna = sum(~mod(A,2),1) % sum(pares,2)

% indices lógicos
cuales_filas_tienen_pares = cantidad_de_pares_por_fila >0 
cuales_columnas_tienen_pares = cantidad_de_pares_por_columna >0

% indices enumerados
cuales_filas_tienen_pares_idx=find(cuales_filas_tienen_pares)
cuales_columnas_tienen_pares_idx =find(cuales_columnas_tienen_pares )
```

**Recursos**

- [Find()](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/266149-convert-logical-into-sequential-index-vector)
- [sum(...,axis)](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/105090-how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-each-row-in-a-matrix)
- [m mod n](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html)
- [index logical keeping shape](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/298083-keep-m-n-structure-after-indexing-a-matrix)
- [randi](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/298083-keep-m-n-structure-after-indexing-a-matrix)

Lo anterior para obtener las filas que contienen almenos un par.

Para probar con que todas sean pares, puedes sumar los impares y si es igual a cero entonces quiere decir que todos eran pares...

En resumen, para saber las  columnas que todos sus elementos son pares:

```
sum(mod(A,2),1)==0
```

Comment: ¿Y si hay números impares que se neutralizan entre ellos?

**Por ejemplo:** `{2, 5, -5 , 6}` o `{2, 7, -1, 6}`. Ahí la suma daría `0 +1 -1 + 0 =0.` Sería bueno que lo encerraras dentro de un `abs()`

Comment: mod(A,2) te resultaría en: `0,1,1,0`. nota que la suma no es en los valores numéricos si no en una "bandera" que se vuelve 1 si es impar. entonces al sumar `sum([0,1,1,0])` obtienes 2, que es el número de impares, como es distinto de cero significa que no todos son pares.